# AngularJs Communicate with Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to call a method that is defined in a Directive from a Controller?

```
.directive('directive', function() {
  return { 
  link:  function(scope, elements, attrs, controller) {   
      scope.func = function(){}
  }
```

and I want to call func from the Controller.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the function within the directive?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understood your question correctly.

You can define a controller for your directive:

```
.directive('directive', function() {
  return { 
  controller: myCtrl,
  link:  function(scope, elements, attrs, controller) {   
  scope.func = function(){}
}
```

Then, `scope` will point to that controllers scope